# Layout Design layout x next to layout y

Tags: android, android-layout

I have some problem designing a layout

1. Layout has Textview and another customlayout

I want to put customLayout Next to Textview. It looks quite simple but my problem is when textview size increases the custom layout is going out of view .

when it reaches end Textview should elipsize and customlayout must come next to it just as in small text case .

Comment: Give the Views fixed widths, so that the TextView doesn't grow to pull the other View away.

Comment: i cannot give fixed width to textview as i dont know how many characters it might have

Comment: The answer is in your question: `when it reaches end Textview should elipsize` And this is only possible if the TextView has a **fixed size**.

Answer (score 0):

Set both of these attributes in your `<TextView>` tag

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:lines="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to set maxWidth for your textview

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="test"
        android:maxWidth="???"

        />
```

## Now what will be the max width for your textview?

- Just get the width for your `custom layout` and minus it from your device total width `(deviceWidth-customLayout Width)` that will be the maximum width for your `textview`.
- So you have to calculate it programatically and set maximum width for your `textview` programatically. it will work.

Comment: let me try this , but if found any easy solution would be great :-)

Comment: I think this is easy ;)